# Fullcalendar restrict view to today + x months

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using the fullcalendar library.  How can i restrict my months view to only see the next x number months?

I dont see any straight forward answers to this in the documentation.  I am not sure if I am supposed to try and alter the render methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    viewDisplay: function(view) {
        // maybe return false aborts action? 
        if (view.start > lastDayOfNextMonth) {
            return false;
        }
        // or disable next button if this is last valid month
        if (view.end + oneDay >= lastValidDate) {
            $("#calendar #fc-button-next").attr("disabled","disabled");
        }
        // or gotoDate if view.start is out of range
        if (view.start > lastValidDate) {
           // proceed
        }
    }
});
```

This question has a bunch of samples:  [FullCalendar examples](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/)